# Is there a way to use wget on a wildcard?

Tags: linux, shell, wget

Is it possible to use wget command for linux in order to get all files in a directory tree of a website?

I can recursively get all of a website with mirror and such, but I would like to just get all files in a single directory. In my mind, it would look something like:

```
    wget http://www.somesite.com/here/is/some/folders/*
```

This would download ALL files (doesn't have to recursively look in subdirectories) in the /folders/ directory.  But the wildcard character doesn't seem to work with wget so I am looking for the correct way.

Comment: As you can't get filelist on http, you can't use wildcards.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, there's `wget -r`, which will recurse down everything under `folders/`, provided there's an index to recurse through.

The other thing you can do is if there's an `index.htm` or whatever in the `folders` directory, you can grep, sed, and cut your way through chaining wget to wget, like so:

```
wget -qO - http://foo/folder/index.htm | sed 's/href=/#/' | cut -d\# -f2 | \
  while read url; do wget $url; done
```

which is generally what I do when I need to scrape and I can't recurse for whichever reason.

edit:

probably want to add `--no-parent` and set `--domain` properly. The [wget manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) is actually pretty good and covers this stuff.

Comment: couldn't get your sed | cut to work cleanly for my case, ended up doing something like `wget -O - http://foo | sed -n 's#^.*href="\([^"]\{1,\}\)".*$#\1#p' | while read url; ...`